# How to save a python dictionary of pandas dataframes to open in R as a list of dataframes

Tags: python, r

I have a dictionary of 104 pandas dataframes

How do i save this as a format i can open in R?

Python Dictionary > R List

There has been some talk of json, but i am hitting a wall.

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers here, but the simplest is probably just to save a directory of CSVs.

Comment: You could use `feather` for transfer between Python and R. More info [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/)